# MyPHP and SQL creating a new table based on others

Tags: mysql

I have three tables; **Table 1 (appointments)** that contains the appointment start and end time in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format, provider ID, Customer ID and Service ID. 
**Table 2 (users)** contains both Provider and Customer IDs and First/Last names. 
**Table 3 (services)** contains the service ID, service name, and service description.

I need to create a **fourth table, called display,** that will display the Provider name, Client name, Service name, and start and end times in HH:MM format.

I've tried googling joins, but I'm not seeming to get anywhere. 
I'm using a simple script from w3schools, below:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ea_appointments INNER JOIN ea_services";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Start: " . $row["start_datetime"]. "End: " . $row["end_datetime"]. " - Provider: " . $row["id_users_provider"]. " - Customer: " . $row["id_users_customer"]. " - Service: " . $row["id_services"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 appointments";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You are missing the join conditions (`on` clause).

Comment: Can you please share your table schema with some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

In this case do not create a table because you just want to combine data from various tables. Just have a query or create a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html).

In the query you need to tell mysql how to join your tables using the `on` clause. I'll show you how to join 2 tables, the rest is up to you:

```
SELECT *
FROM ea_appointments a
INNER JOIN ea_services s on a.serviceid=s.serviceid
```